# Can't install Rails on my system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xcode

I keep getting the following error. I have rvm 1.25.17 (stable), ruby 2.1.0p0 revision 44422. Also, I checked my Xcode install and I think it's up to date (3.2 in /Developer and 5.0.2 in /Applications). At some point, an error told me that my Xcode might not be installed. I'm getting back into programming after a long break and am at a loss. Just trying to get setup on some Ruby on Rails...

```
Fetching: atomic-1.1.14.gem (100%)

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/ecualombian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/ecualombian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby
    --with-atomic_reference-dir
    --without-atomic_reference-dir
    --with-atomic_reference-include
    --without-atomic_reference-include=${atomic_reference-dir}/include
    --with-atomic_reference-lib
    --without-atomic_reference-lib=${atomic_reference-dir}/lib
/Users/ecualombian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/ecualombian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:541:in `try_link0'
    from /Users/ecualombian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:840:in `try_run'
    from extconf.rb:26:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/ecualombian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/atomic-1.1.14 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/ecualombian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/2.1.0-static/atomic-1.1.14/gem_make.out
```

Comment: provide the your system and `mkmf.log`

Answer (score 1):

From XCode 5.0.1 onwards, you can install commandline tools from the terminal. Here's the command, please run this on your Terminal:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Once it's installed, try installing the gems again.

Answer (score 0):

Basically atomic gem expects you to have developer tools like gcc 4.2 which you can install view brew or simply install XCode command like tools, reinstall ruby via rvm and then install rails.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing command line tools for Xcode, that are required for gcc and make. Install the same from Xcode-> Preferences-> Downloads, or from the command line with xcode-select --install, and then retry installing Rails.